# Accessing an attribute of a variable typed as Union throws an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-typing

I'm a bit confused about the usage of `Union` in Python static typing.

```
class A():
    foo: int = 10

class B():
    bar: str = 'hello'

def get_object() -> Union[A, B]:
    return B()

var = get_object()
var.bar
```

The above snippet returns `error: Item "A" of "Union[A, B]" has no attribute "bar"`

The docs state

> The interaction between Intersection and Union is complex but should be no surprise if you understand the interaction between intersections and unions of regular sets

Which lead me to believe that **a variable of type `Union[A, B]` could be used as though it were of type `A` or `B`, without the type checker throwing errors**. Is this incorrect?

If so, how could I achieve a functionality that would mimic this? (*i.e a value from `get_object` could be used as though it were of type `A` or `B`*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes `Union[A,B]` means that value can be **either** of type `A` **or** of type `B`..

This does **not** imply that you can treat the value as if it was `A` or `B` at your choice. That's precisely the use of an intersection type.

When you have a `Union[A,B]` you have to check if the value is `A`, and if so handle it like `A`, or if it is `B`, and handle it like a `B`. The advantage is that you know that it wont be an other type `C`, so you have a defined list of types to check against. But you still need to check in some way.